# knockout model to coffeescript class syntax conversion

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript, knockout-2.0

So I'm trying to convert a knockout model into a coffeescript class, haven't used coffee until now, having trouble with a syntax in how to call the property.subscribe knockout function, via coffeescript (and in my class). Presently the code looks like (severely dumbed down to get point across)

```
var Autocomplete = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.displayResults = ko.observable(false);
  self.results = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.hasResults = ko.observable(false);

    self.hasResults.subscribe(function(newValue){
        if(newValue == true) {
            self.displayResults(true);
        } else {
            self.displayResults(false);
        }
    });

}
```

But basically what Im trying to do is:

```
class ClientAutoComplete
  constructor: ->
    @hasResults = ko.observable(false)  
    @results = ko.observableArray([])  
    @displayResults = ko.observable(false)

  hasResults.subscribe: (newValue) ->
    @displayResults(newValue)
```

What I cant figure out is how to call the property.subscribe method correctly, ive tried a couple different syntaxes but to no avail. Can anyone shed any light on this? Much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of your JavaScript would be this:

```
class ClientAutoComplete
  constructor: ->
    @displayResults = ko.observable(false)
    @results = ko.observableArray([])  
    @hasResults = ko.observable(false)  

    @hasResults.subscribe (newValue) =>
      @displayResults(newValue)
```

You have to add `@` to `hasResults` to make it into an instance variable reference and you need to indent `@hasResults.subscribe` another level to get it into the constructor. You also don't want a colon on `@hasResults.subscribe`, that's a function call, not a property definition; you could also write it like this:

```
@hasResults.subscribe( (newValue) =>
  @displayResults(newValue)
)
```

if you need to be reminded that it is a function call. I tend to include the parentheses if the anonymous function is bigger than a one-liner.

The [fat-arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) binds the anonymous function to the current `this`:

> The fat arrow `=>` can be used to both define a function, and to bind it to the current value of `this`, right on the spot. This is helpful when using callback-based libraries like Prototype or jQuery, for creating iterator functions to pass to `each`, or event-handler functions to use with `bind`. Functions created with the fat arrow are able to access properties of the `this` where they're defined.

The fat-arrow is the usual replacement for the `var self = this;` JavaScript idiom.

Comment: I actually tried that however I was getting a parse error, unexpected { on line x -- But since you guided me in right direction I was able to get it working via:     @hasResults.subscribe (newValue) =>
      @displayResults(newValue) (note the apparent need for no colon after the subscribe)

Comment: @thrice801: Sorry, I missed that colon. Anyway, I updated the answer to cover that part too.